# How to multiply all elements in an doubles list?

Tags: c#, list

How do I multiply the contents of a `list <double>`?

```
List<double> mult=new List<double>{3, 5, 10};
```

So far I have:

```
double r=0.0;
for(int i=0;i<mult.Count;i++)
{
    r=mult[i]*mult[(i+1)];
}
```

Comment: Unclear question. What are you trying to achieve? Did you even try to run your code sample?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To fix your loop, start with `1.0` and multiply each item in the list, like this:

```
double r = 1.0;
for(int i = 0; i < mult.Count; i++)
{
    r = r * mult[i]; // or equivalently r *= mult[i];
}
```

But for simplicity, you could use a little Linq with the [`Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate.aspx) extension method:

```
double r = mult.Aggregate((a, x) => a * x);
```

Comment: @EdwardKarak The `Aggregate` method starts with the first element of the list, and applies some transform (in this case, just multiplying) to each subsequent element, using the result of the previous transform in the next one. Refer to the documentation for more info.

Comment: @EdwardKarak that's a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx), also called an anonymous function. It creates a function which accepts two parameters, an 'accumulator', `a`, and the next item in the sequence, `x`, and returns their product, `a * x`. The result will be passed back into the function for the next item, and so on, for all items in the list. Finally, it will return the accumulator.

Comment: @EdwardKarak See also See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)

Comment: Of course the explicit loop can also be written as `double r = 1.0; foreach (var m in mult) { r *= m; }`. It is easier to use `foreach` in simple cases where you don't need the index.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by multiply? If you like to calculate the product, then your code is wrong and the correct code is

```
double r=1.0;
for(int i=0;i<mult.Count;i++)
{
    r *= mult[i];
}
```